# CCLabelTTF won't get released and removed

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have a synthesized CCLabelTTF called `self.startDate`, but the following does not remove the label:

```
[self.startDate removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
self.startDate=nil;
```

This technique works fine for pointers to sprites, but not for labels?

The label remains on the screen, and if I then re-create the label and assign it to another CCLabelTTF (with different text), I then get 2 labels overlapping.

My property is set as `assign` so there is no iOS ownership going on outside the Cocos heirarchy, so no extra retention of the label should be happening. I've seen various bugs listed with CCLabelTTF in other places, so I'm wondering if this is in fact a known issue, where labels don't always get removed from screen as you'd expect?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through removeFromParentAndCleanup and seeing if you can spot the issue?

Comment: no dice. just doesn't get removed, no obvious reason why. i'll try switching to a bmfont

Comment: What version of cocos2d are you running?

Comment: do you have changed the value of `startDate` twice ??

Comment: @InderKumarRathore not sure I understand your question; `self.startDate` is an iVar; after removing it with the above code, it remains on the screen. I have also tried referencing the label by tag instead of iVar and also tried using bmfont; the issue remains entirely. sprites are removed easily using the same method and work fine.

Comment: have you tried `self.startDate.tag = 12345` and then remove child by tag?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore yes, as I mentioned in my last reponse to you

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how you create and add the label? If you're not using ARC, maybe you simply retained the autorelease label (by sending it the retain message). Or maybe you created the label twice by accident, but you're removing only one. Also check what the [startDate retainCount] values are before and after removing it from parent.

Comment: thanks, all good ideas. i've since moved on from this problem and have decided not to remove the label and am doing something different. but the pointers here are good to remember in general.

Answer (score 0):

CCLabelTTF is just a subclass of CCSprite with rendered font as texture. So it will work the same as CCSprite. Make sure your removeFromParentAndCleanup: method is called after adding to parent, not before.

Comment: Thanks, but since the label is visible on the screen, then it has already been added to parent. Removing it from parent does not remove it from screen.

Comment: i didn't say, that it is not added at all. just place breakpoint at line with removeFromParentAndCleanup: method and make sure that in that moment label's parent is not nil

Comment: omg, dude, just check. if you cannot remove CCNode from parent node, the first thing that you should suggest, that in that moment it have no parent.

Comment: There is no need to insult me; I am investigating all answers. Your suggestion after my testing does not appear to be the issue. The label is added to the same parent as other sprites. At the same time, I can remove other sprites using the same technique, therefore the parent is there. And also, if there was no parent, how would the node even be visible?

Comment: for example, if label was added AFTER you tried to remove it from parent

Answer (score -1):

use following code

[self removeChild:self.startDate cleanup:YES];

Comment: that's not a solution, it's effectively the same operation but using a different function